# Wrong MTU size - what issue should I expect?

Tags: networking, interface, mtu

I'm configuring several network interface and I noticed that some software clients declare jumbo frame at 9000 other at 9216. I'm setting everything at 9216 on all the interfaces.

Everything seems working fine.
However, what kind of networking issue I should expect as issue if MTU was misconfigurated on some appliance?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no standard for jumbo frames, and different vendors do it differently. The IEEE ethernet standards do not provide for jumbo frames, and the ethernet MTU is 1500. Some vendors even have different jumbo frame sizes for different devices models. For example, it is not unusual to find switches that only support 3K jumbo frames. You need to make sure that all the network devices support what you are configuring on the hosts.

Answer (score 0):

MTU != max frame size

The MTU is the *maximum payload* a frame can carry (ie. the maximum IP packet size) while the maximum frame size is the *maximum size of the total frame*.

If you add the L2 overhead to the MTU you get the maximum frame size - 18 bytes for untagged frames, 22 bytes for 802.1q tagged frames.

Some vendors use dubious terms like "L2 MTU" or don't count the FCS field. Only when you can't clear this up, you should set all NICs to the exact same size and the switches to 22 bytes larger.